Passing the Class Variables from one class to another
I have two classes, A and B. I will only be setting the values of class A and I want class B variables to hold the same value as class A or have have access to all values of class A variables.  In my case, class A and B should not be inherited logically. Is this possible without inheritance?.
In the below code, I have given an example where I need the value of only one variable and I could have passed the name as a method param. But, in my actual project I need to set the value of 20+ variables and it is not easy to pass around 20+ values to another class.


class B {
  name: string
  age: number

  print() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const b = new B();

class A {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  printValues() {
    b.print()
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.name = "TOM"
a.printValues() // Want to Print TOM




Why not create an object that consists of just the shared data and have both ClassA and ClassB access the data via that object?

That is not [tag:javascript]; please tag appropriately.

There is no way u can do it, unless u have a relation between them. Either u can inherit or  assign values of the class A to class B during the setting of class A variables !!

How is the A class supposed to know which instance of B should be linked to each A instance?

A should have a property that links it to a B instance. Then you can use a setter to pass the name assignment through.


class B {
  name: string
  age: number

  print() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const b = new B();

class A {
  age: number;
  b: B;

  constructor(b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.b.name;
  };

  set name(new_name) {
    this.b.name = new_name;
  }

  printValues() {
    this.b.print()
  }
}

const a = new A(b);
a.name = "TOM"
a.printValues() // Want to Print TOM




Or the A should pass itself to b.print()

You can simultaneously assign values to both instances with Proxy:


class B{
  print() {
    Object.entries(this).forEach(([k,v]) => console.log(k, ':', v));
  }
}

const b = new B();

class A {
  constructor(b){
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(_, prop, val, proxy){
        b[prop] = val;
        return Reflect.set(...arguments);
      }
    });
  }
  printValues() {
    b.print()
  }
}

const a = new A(b);

a.name = "TOM";
a.age = 33;
a.printValues() // Want to Print TOM



But better save b in the a instance with the A's constructor argument or create b in the A's constructor.
